# setJMenuBar not working

Tags: java, swing

After extensive googling I've found that this issue is generally case-specific. I've tried many of the solutions found and none of them have worked for me, so I felt it was appropriate to create a post on it.

I'm using setJMenuBar and the bar is never appearing, here is my code:

NOTE: I believe the cause is that I update the frame, however the solution is still unknown.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class testclass extends JFrame { 


    public int updateRate = 60;

    public int screenWidth;
    public int screenHeight;

    public boolean finishedInitialPaint;

    private Graphics bufferGraphics;
    private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;

    public int gridSize = 10;

    JMenuBar engineBar;
    JMenu fileMenu, editMenu, createMenu, toolsMenu, panelsMenu;
    JMenuItem fileNewScene, fileOpenScene, fileSaveScene, fileExit;
    JMenuItem editPreferences, editEngine;
    JMenuItem createEmpty, createStandard;
    JMenuItem toolsDebug;
    JMenuItem panelView2D, panelEditor2D, panelHierarchy, panelInspector, panelExplorer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testclass testClassv = new testclass ();
    }

    public testclass () {
        Start ();

        while(true) {
            Update ();
            ClearBackBuffer ();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 / updateRate);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

    }

    private void Start () {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        screenHeight = screenSize.height;

        CreateDefaultEngineMenu ();

        setTitle("Test Window");
        setSize(Math.round(screenWidth * 0.99f), Math.round(screenHeight * 0.9f));
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void CreateDefaultEngineMenu () {
        engineBar = new JMenuBar ();

        /*
         * Building initial menus
         */

    // Build the file menu
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        engineBar.add(fileMenu);

    // Build the edit menu
        editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        engineBar.add(editMenu);

    // Build the create menu
        createMenu = new JMenu("Create");
        engineBar.add(createMenu);

    // Build the tools menu
        toolsMenu = new JMenu("Tools");
        engineBar.add(toolsMenu);

    // Build the panels menu
        panelsMenu = new JMenu("Panels");
        engineBar.add(panelsMenu);

        /*
         *  Building menu options
         */

    // File menu options
        fileNewScene = new JMenuItem("New Scene");
        fileMenu.add(fileNewScene);
        fileOpenScene = new JMenuItem("Open Scene");
        fileMenu.add(fileOpenScene);
        fileSaveScene = new JMenuItem("Save Scene");
        fileMenu.add(fileSaveScene);
        fileExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        fileMenu.add(fileExit);

    // Edit menu options
        editPreferences = new JMenuItem ("Preferences");
        editMenu.add(editPreferences);
        editEngine = new JMenuItem ("Engine Settings");
        editMenu.add(editEngine);

    // Create menu options
        createEmpty = new JMenuItem("New Empty GameObject");
        createMenu.add(createEmpty);
        createStandard = new JMenuItem("Standard GameObjects");
        createMenu.add(createStandard);

    // Tools menu options
        toolsDebug = new JMenuItem ("Debug");
        toolsMenu.add(toolsDebug);

    // Panels menu options
        panelView2D = new JMenuItem("View 2D");
        panelsMenu.add(panelView2D);
        panelEditor2D = new JMenuItem("Editor 2D");
        panelsMenu.add(panelEditor2D);
        panelHierarchy = new JMenuItem("Hierarchy");
        panelsMenu.add(panelHierarchy);
        panelInspector = new JMenuItem("Inspector");
        panelsMenu.add(panelInspector);
        panelExplorer = new JMenuItem("Explorer");
        panelsMenu.add(panelExplorer);


        // Set the frame to use the bar
        setJMenuBar(engineBar);
    }

    private void Update () {
        //sceneObjects.activeObjects.get(0).transform.position.x += 0.1f;
        initialize ();
        ClearBackBuffer ();
        repaint ();
        DrawBackBufferToScreen ();
    }

    private void initialize () {
        if(bufferStrategy == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(2);
            bufferStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
            bufferGraphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // Something to go here
    }

    private void ClearBackBuffer () {
        bufferGraphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        try {
            bufferGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)bufferGraphics;
            paint2D(g2d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Debug.EngineLogError("Engine", "Failed to clear rect for frame buffer (Failed to draw frame) - Exception");
        } finally {
            bufferGraphics.dispose();
        }
    }

    private void DrawBackBufferToScreen () {
        bufferStrategy.show();
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    private void paint2D (Graphics2D g2d) {
        // Multi-Used Variables
        int canvasWidth = Math.round(screenWidth / 2);
        int canvasHeight = Math.round(screenHeight / 2);

        // Draw panel borders
        // View2D
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.drawRect((canvasWidth) - (canvasWidth / 2) - 1, canvasHeight - (Math.round(canvasHeight / 1.35f)) - 1, canvasWidth + 1, canvasHeight + 1);
    }

}
```

Any and all relevant answers are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed code to be able to be tested raw

Comment: `"After extensive googling..."` -- you should have also found the [help] link, especially the how-to-ask and [mcve] links that it contains. Please read these and then improve this question so that it is more easily answered.

Comment: I removed irrelevant ramble and tidied things up

Comment: Please re-read the link -- we can't directly copy, compile and run this code as there is no class body, no main method, no imports... You're missing all the components that the MCVE link states that you need.

Comment: I apologize, it was a large class and out of laziness I had just grabbed the relevant area and removed irrelevant code. I've reworked the class for the example so that it can be run as is.

Comment: "it was a large class" : always post [mcve]. (Writing a minimal case is a good debugging technique. In doing so you are likely to solve your problem.)

Comment: You did create an MCVE quickly. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot wrong in your code, but the biggest problem is here:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // Something to go here
}
```

By overriding paint, you're preventing the JFrame from doing its necessary painting of itself, its borders, and relevant to your problem, its child components. So your menu never draws!

You should never draw directly in the JFrame, but if you absolutely must (and you don't), at least call the super's painting method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    // Something to go here
}
```

Better still-- never override paint but instead draw inside a JPanel's `paintComponent` method (still calling the super's paintComponent method within) and display that JPanel within your JFrame.

Key links:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

---

I'm not sure what the rest of your code is trying to do, but you've got big threading issues, other painting issues,... do read the tutorials to avoid guessing. Also you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Rather than using super.paint(g), I created my own buffer method with the initialize, clearBackbuffer, and DrawBackbufferToScreen methods. Using super.paint(g) was avoided so that flickering did not occur when re-drawing so much, so relative to my code this solution does not work (It would work if I wasn't updating / re-drawing, but I am)

Comment: @kriller509: Have you read anything that I've said? You're doing things wrong, starting with drawing directly in the JFrame. Your "solution" above is bad, don't do it. Starting with **never** drawing directly in the JFrame. You avoid flickering by using double buffering which JPanel's `paintComponent` does for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is right, you are doing some things wrong here.

Comment: @kriller509: before doing anything else, please check the links that I've added to my answer, especially the 2nd one. It will give you all the details that you need to fully understand the problem.

Comment: Beyond your condescending remarks towards someone who was clearly having difficulty I found your answer to be overall helpful. So thanks, I guess?

Comment: @kriller509; Only condescending when you completely ignored my suggestions. Sorry, but hard not to be.

Comment: @kriller509: what you need to understand that a JFrame is a very complex beast. It is composed of multiple sub-components, and has both "light-weight" and "heavy-weight" parts, the latter which interact directly with the OS's painting mechanisms, and if you muck with the painting of this component, you do so at your own risk. Best to leave its painting alone, and do your graphics all within a fully light-weight component such as a JPanel.